# Connection to server fails after waking from sleep

Tags: snow-leopard, network

I connect to my Windows computer with my MBP using `Connect to Server` (using smb://192.x.x.x).

For a reason I can't explain, it works well when I do it but if I close my laptop (meaning closing the screen, not turning power off) and reopen it, almost 90% of the time, I won't be able to access the remote computer.

The only way to solve the problem and be able to reconnect is to reboot the macbook.  I use Snow Leopard.

Does anyone know a fix for this ?

**Update:** I forgot to say I see I'm still connected but I can't 'eject' the mount.  I just does nothing.

Comment: Do you see any output in Console, perchance?

Comment: I don't get what you mean with your question.  Sorry.

Comment: Open Console from /Applications/Utilities, and see if anything looks relevant.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I'll try to replicate the problem again and see if I can find something there.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes a network device may stay "connected" even though the connection isn't working properly. Try manually ejecting it from the Finder sidebar, if it appears there:

[image]

Then try connecting again with <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

If that doesn't work, [this question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/10593/how-can-i-force-unmount-a-network-device-on-mac) suggests some more possible solutions.

Comment: Is the key combination the samething as clicking on 'eject' ? I updated my question to say the eject was not working.  Thanks for the other link, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

From the Terminal

`mount | grep smb | awk {'print$3'} | xargs -t umount -f`

This will forcibly unmount all smb mounted shares.